# java.lang.Object[] cannot be converted to java.lang.String[]

Tags: java, string

```
public class Mass_Reading
{
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
   {
     CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("Test_Graphs.csv"));

     List myEntries = reader.readAll();
     //System.out.println(myEntries);

     myEntries = new ArrayList<String>(myEntries);
     //System.out.println(myEntries);

     Object[] data = myEntries.toArray();
     System.out.println(data[0] + "");
     }
}
```

I'm trying to read a .csv file in and get the data into a workable data type. When read in it starts as a List of String Objects. In my code above I'm trying to get it to an array of Strings. My main hangup is getting the String Object to a String Literal. I keep getting the error java.lang.Object[] cannot be converted to java.lang.String[]. The code above compiles, but still does not achieve my goal. When it prints I still get a String Object. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you paste the stacktrace and identify what line in your code is giving the error?

Answer (score 6):

Use this code:

```
String[] data = myEntries.toArray(new String[myEntries.size()]);
```

The method that you call, `myEntries.toArray()`, always returns an `Object[]`, which cannot be cast to a `String[]`.

But there is an overloaded method that I call in the example above, in which you can pass in the right type of array as an argument. The `toArray()` method will then fill the passed in array if it is of sufficient size.

If it is not of sufficient size, it will create a new array of the right type (the same type as the argument that you passed in)

Because of that, you can also write:

```
String[] data = myEntries.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Some people prefer that, but I don't like the fact that this creates one wasted object, although in a real application this won't make a difference in performance.

Comment: I don't have it on hand, but apparently in versions newer than Java 6, the zero array is actually faster.